# wintab32.dll is missing, causes crash?

Tags: c++, qt, dependencies, mingw

I built Qt 5.5.1 from source using MinGW 5.3.0 compiler, both for 32 as well as 64 bit.
If I run my application deployed with these created libraries, it works fine.
But if I run Dependency Walker, it shows the yellow question mark symbol for ***wintab32.dll***, which is not present on my Windows 7 PC. The error it is showing is

```
LoadLibraryW("C:\Windows\system32\wintab32.dll") called from "QT5CORE.DLL" at address 0x0000000000646E4E.

LoadLibraryW("C:\Windows\system32\wintab32.dll") returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
```

Should I be worried about deploying my application, or I am getting this error because I am running on non-tablet PC? If my build is corrupted, then please let me know.

I used the following args for configure while building Qt:

```
cd c:\Qt\5.5.1\32\

SET PATH=C:\Qt\5.5.1\32\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1\qtbase\bin;C:\Qt\5.5.1\32\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1\gnuwin32\bin;C:\MinGW\5.3.0\mingw32\bin;%PATH%

SET QMAKESPEC=win32-g++

qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1\configure -debug-and-release -opensource -no-opengl -no-openssl -skip qt3d -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtandroidextras -skip qtcanvas3d -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdeclarative -skip qtdoc -skip qtenginio -skip qtgraphicaleffects -skip qtimageformats -skip qtlocation -skip qtmacextras -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtquick1 -skip qtquickcontrols -skip qtscript -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialport -skip qtsvg -skip qttools -skip qttranslations -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebkit -skip qtwebkit-examples -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtwinextras -skip qtx11extras -skip qtxmlpatterns -confirm-license -nomake tests -nomake examples

mingw32-make
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this piece of text from the source code of Qt 5.5, `qwindowstabletsupport.cpp`

```
bool QWindowsWinTab32DLL::init()
{
    if (wTInfo)
        return true;
    QSystemLibrary library(QStringLiteral("wintab32"));
```

so it might be relevant for drawing tablets. Qt library might change it's behaviour (user input etc.) if this library can be loaded to memory, but it is probably ok if it cannot be loaded.

When depends programs is used to open an executable or a library (File/Open), there will be an error dialog with text

> Errors were detected when processing "\path to library\X.dll"  See the
>   log file for details.

if a library absolutely required by the executable or library cannot be found.

Comment: So should this be reported as a Qt bug? This call should only be made on tablets, then why it is being made on PC.

Comment: @Cool_Coder if only Dependency walker complains, it is not a bug. A program might just be checking if it can provide some additional features by trying to load a library that may not exists.

Comment: But the yellow question means that the dll is necessary and not optional, right? For example, the plugins that are required for the program to run are not shown in dependency walker, so no error for plugins. Shouldn't it be similar for this one too?

Comment: @Cool_Coder When depends programs finds that a library that a program absolutely needs, is missing, it pops out a dialog with text "Errors were detected when processing "<path to dll>/X.dll" See the log file for details."

Comment: Yeah it shows that dialog for 32 bit profiling. For 64 bit, it simply crashes my program.